# Spring-Hibernate using multiple datasource/database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working on a web application that uses Spring MVC 3 and Hibernate

I want to use 2 datasource MySql and Oracle databases for my web application,

I've been read many tutorial and problem solving for "spring-hibernate multiple datasource/database"
for example :

[directjump2java.blogspot.com](http://directjump2java.blogspot.com/2012/05/hibernate-setting-up-multiple-databases.html)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541736/hibernate-configuring-multiple-datasources-and-multiple-session-factories)

[forum spring](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/102639-spring-3-hibernate-3-with-multiple-datasources-best-practice)

and etc.

but when every single time I run it, the config just read my first database config (MySql)
and show this error `Table 'db_prod.ksei_lookup_holiday' doesn't exist` db.prod is my first database(MySql) and KSEI_LOOKUP_HOLIDAY is my second database (Oracle),

this is my spring.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerSOAAPP"/>
<context:annotation-config />


<context:component-scan base-package="prod.support" />

<!-- Database MySql, Desktop -->

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_prod" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="shikamaru" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"></property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="prod.support.model.splatter" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>

<!-- Database Oracle, Schema : SOAAPP -->

<bean id="dataSourceSOAAPP" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
    <property name="username" value="splatter" />
    <property name="password" value="shikamaru" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactorySOAAPP"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"></property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="prod.support.model.soaapp" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerSOAAPP"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactorySOAAPP">
</bean>
```

this is my DAO Implementation for my first database (MySql)

```
@Repository
@Qualifier(value="sessionFactory")
public class UserDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDao{

@Autowired
private UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```

this is my DAO Implementation for my second database (Oracle)

```
@Repository
@Qualifier(value="sessionFactorySOAAPP")
public class UpdateKSEIDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UpdateKSEIDao{

@Autowired
private UpdateKSEIDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactorySOAAPP){
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactorySOAAPP);
}
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have used

`<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>` in `sessionFactorySOAAPP`.

You should have used `<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSOAAPP"></property>`

Answer (score 2):

If you check "sessionFactorySOAAPP" then the below property name should be 'dataSourceSOAAPP' not the 'dataSource'.

Answer (score 0):

this my configuration file:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
              value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gl?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="2238295" />
</bean>



<bean id="mainDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
              value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gl_main?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="2238295" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="sfAccounting"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gl.domain.accounting" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="sfCommon"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gl.domain.common" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManagerAccounting"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManagerCommon"/>

<bean id="txnManagerAccounting"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sfAccounting" />

</bean>


<bean id="txnManagerCommon"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sfCommon" />

</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@geoand is correct in the error he spotted. Other than that the context xml seems correct and works for me.
However, for me, this only works if @qualifier is with the @Autowired.

```
@Repository
public class BusinessDaoImpl implements BusinessDao
{
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="sessionFactory")
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```