# Spring Datasources based on Environment

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to configure my Spring Boot application to use specific datasources when certain environmental variables exist. For example, if the `MY_PROD_DATASOURCE` environmental variable exists, I would like to use my production datasource; otherwise, I would like to use my local datasource (of the same type).

I have found [something in the Spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) that explains how a single datasource could be declared in my `application.properties`. Specifically, a MySQL datasource could look like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

However, I do not see how I could change the datasource properties conditionally in this file. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can define multiple Session Factories with different datasource files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541736/hibernate-configuring-multiple-datasources-and-multiple-session-factories

Comment: Can you expand upon that a little more? Perhaps in an answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Spring Boot you can:

1. Externalize `application.properties` from your jar and provide file per environment by adding path as a startup parameter:

   ```
   java -jar your-app.jar --spring.config.location=/path/to/app.properties
   ```
2. Use Spring profiles. Create `application-${profile}.properties` for each profile, in each one different datasource properties
3. Use Spring profiles and instead of `application.properties`, put your properties to `application.yaml` where you can put properties for all environments using convention as below:

   ```
   spring:
       profiles: development
   server:
       port: 9001

   ---

   spring:
       profiles: production
   server:
       port: 0
   ```
4. Use environment variables and set `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME`, `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD`, and (optionally) `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME`.

Learn more in the Spring Boot reference section on [*How to change configuration depending on the environment*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) and [*External Configuration*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).

Comment: That looks like what I'm trying to do! However, I have a follow-up question: does this mean that I cannot use the `@Configuration` and/or the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations in my app?

Comment: You can and you should.