# How can I develop an application which will run on more than one database at a same time using Spring + Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multiple-databases

I am developing a Java application using Spring + Hibernate. i want this application to run on more then one Database on same time.

> For Example if user tries to search for some data, Application has to search for that data in all the configured data-sources at a same time.

I am looking for a solution which will create different threads for each data-source and when user perform any operation all the threads needs to perform that operation

**Edit 1**
Let me explain my problem in detail below is my DAO class

```
@Repository("engineDAO")
public class EngineDAOImpl implements EngineDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void persistEngine(Engine engine, String[] DataSourceNames) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(engine);
    }
}
```

Now from service class i will call `persistEngine` method of `EngineDAO` class with argument as `String[] DataSourceNames` so this operation needs to be performed on all the Data-sources provided as argument. What all changes i have to make for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So the databases will have identical content?  Or does your application have to decide which database or databases to store each item in?

Comment: Did you think about database replication instead?

Comment: It’s like I am trying to examine the stat of data for all the configured database. So application has to perform the same operation on all the configured databases.

Comment: If all the databases have to have identical content, then you should use a replication solution, rather than trying to implement this at the level of an application.  Read up on the replication options that are available for whatever DBMS you are using.

Comment: Content will be different in all the database, operations which application will perform will be same.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `SessionFactory` or `EntityManagerFactory` objects, each associated with different `DataSource`. If you want to manage transaction across different datasources I would recommend to use `JTA Transaction Manager`. If your application is not running in Java EE environment, you can use some 3rd party JTA transaction manager, for example `Atomikos Transaction Manager`

There are some threads at Stackoverflow that discuss about this problem. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541736/hibernate-configuring-multiple-datasources-and-multiple-session-factories)

**Edit 1**:
If you neet to select  datasources by name, than your DAO can implement `BeanFactoryAware` and you will obtain `BeanFactory` object, which you can use for accessing `SessionFactory` beans by name. 
Your code should look like something like that

```
@Repository("engineDAO")
public class EngineDAOImpl implements EngineDAO, BeanFactoryAware {

    private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void persistEngine(final Engine engine, final String[] sessionFactoryNames) {
        for (final String sessionFactoryName : sessionFactoryNames) {
            final SessionFactory sessionFactory = beanFactory.getBean(sessionFactoryName, SessionFactory.class);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(engine);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(final BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with given solution is, each time you are adding a new data source you have to go and add a new session factory object in your code, I am looking for some generic solution.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to change your code to add a new `SessionFactory`.  You just need some class that is able to create `SessionFactory` objects.  This is as generic as you're going to get.  @Kushal

Comment: It might be a vary basic thing, but i don't know how to write that generic class which i can use to create `SessionFactory` can you help me out..